# Drawing in Word 2007 - where mouse cursor icon disappeared?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-2007

Drawing in Word 2007 - where mouse cursor icon disappeared ?

It's here on the left in Word 2003...

http://officeimg.vo.msecnd.net/pl-pl/files/018/219/ZA001148935.gif

Comment: http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080211092054AAITpre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the `Select` dropdown on the right side of the Home tab.